# Finding adjacent elements of cell in a matrix

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

I have the following matrix with 25 rows and 13 columns :

```
A       B       C       D       E       F       G       
1 - - - - - - - - - - - 1 - - - - - - - - - - - 1 
| x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x | 
| x x x 1 - - - - - - - 1 - - - - - - - 1 x x x | 
| x x x | x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x | x x x | 
| x x x | x x x 1 - - - 1 - - - 1 x x x | x x x | 
| x x x | x x x | x x x x x x x | x x x | x x x | 
1 x x x 1 x x x 1 x x x x x x x 1 x x x 1 x x x 1 
| x x x | x x x | x x x x x x x | x x x | x x x | 
| x x x | x x x 1 - - - 1 - - - 1 x x x | x x x | 
| x x x | x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x | x x x | 
| x x x 1 - - - - - - - 1 - - - - - - - 1 x x x | 
| x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x | 
1 - - - - - - - - - - - 1 - - - - - - - - - - - 1
```

The rows and columns are divided by 7 and I have put letters on top from A-G to be more visible.In the matrix we have "1".The symbol "1" represent the possible positions to put element from the game https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_men%27s_morris . I am trying to figure out if someone gives me the (x,y) for a cell which has value "1" , how can I find a list of coordinates for all adjacent cells?

I have tried finding if the cell is in the inner rectangle and going further to caclulate directly what is the offset according to Ox and Oy , but it didn't work

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Create a struct that holds x and y coordinates then use a vector for other data structure to store adjacent cells. This can be done by checking if coordinate(x+1,y+1) is adjacent then (x-1,y-1) and so on. You should have for blocks for adjacent cells

Comment: Why did you tag the question both as C++ and Java. What language does your question apply to?

Answer (score 4):

in general to find adjacent cells we can use the following structure:

```
topLeft  = array[ x - 1 ][ y - 1 ]
top      = array[ x     ][ y - 1 ]
topRight = array[ x + 1 ][ y - 1 ]

midLeft  = array[ x - 1 ][ y     ]
midRight = array[ x + 1 ][ y     ]

botLeft  = array[ x - 1 ][ y + 1 ]
bot      = array[ x     ][ y + 1 ]
botRight = array[ x + 1 ][ y + 1 ]
```

Note that the above code can be applied to cells that asde not boundary. Othwerwise you'll get outside the array index range

this is a list of all possible adjacent cells.
it is unclear what you want to do with this adjacent cells so this is as much info i can provide for now.

to answer your question of "how can I find a list of coordinates for all adjacent cells?"

using the above structure you can store the coordinates in a vector,such as:

```
struct cords{
int cordX;
int cordY;
};
```

then once you find a adjacent cell using the above you can do the following

```
cords c;
c.cordX = ...;
c.cordY=...;
vector<cords> coordinates;
coordinates.push_back(c);
```